# Uninstalling a driver via batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, driver, uninstallation, runonce

I'm looking for information on whether or not there is a Windows standard way for accomplishing this?

Essentially we have a vendor who has updated their driver and devices running our software must be updated automatically.

In order to do this, we must uninstall the existing driver first (vendor requirement).

Any guidance on best practices/approach to doing so.  Details of why this needs to be done are probably not important.  It just needs to be done.

Also a sample would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I'm currently looking at trying to use DevCon.  Is there any other way that someone can recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMIC is best choice for accomplishing this via command line.

```
wmic sysdriver where name="drivernamehere" call delete
```

devcon.exe is another alternative for batch.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272

EDIT: Use this to get find the correct name

```
wmic sysdriver get name
```

Comment: How about WMIC using the delete method of Win32_SystemDriver.

Comment: Thanks Knuckle-Dragger.  Is WMIC something that I can use as part of a batch?  Or would I have to manually open up a command prompt and run it?  

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

1. RunOnce entry    
2.  Runs a script (batch I guess)    
3.  Uninstalls existing driver (tablet digitizer driver)    
4.  Installs new updated driver.     

Seems strange, but vendor requires that the existing be uninstalled before their script is run to install the updated one

Comment: You may want to have a read here.  http://superuser.com/questions/243040/can-i-remotely-un-install-an-installed-graphics-driver-on-windows-2008-server

Answer (score 4):

> wmic sysdriver where "name=drivernamehere" call delete

The syntax above appears to be incorrect. I tried and always got "delete - Invalid alias verb"
I looked up the syntax and came up with the following that appears to work:

wmic sysdriver where name="driver_name" delete

I got instance deletion successful but I have to verify whether this completely removes the driver from the system or not.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do a little additional work before posting this solution

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the correct syntax should be as follows:

```
wmic sysdriver where(name="driver_name") delete
```